# uksort does not work - Callback not executed or exception

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to use `uksort` in PHP 5.5 to sort an array by its key. This does not work. Either an exception is thrown, that the specified class is invalid or nothing happens:

```
namespace some\name\space

class myClass extends someClass {
   public function someFunction {
       $theArray = array(
           "key1" => "value1",
           "key2" => "value2",
           ...
           "keyN" => "valueN"
       );

       // Exception "Fatal Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string"
       uksort($theArray, array($this, "sorterFunc"));
       uksort($theArray, array("someClass", "sorterFunc"));
       uksort($theArray, array("some\name\space\someClass", "sorterFunc"));
       uksort($theArray, "self::sorterFunc");
       uksort($theArray, "some\name\space\someClass::sorterFunc");

       // No effect. No logging from sorterFunc and 
       // key/value order stays the same.
       uksort($theArray, "sorterFunc");
       uksort($theArray, "someClass::sorterFunc");
   }

   public static function sorterFunc($a, $b) {
       myLogger->info("sorterFunc called");
       return $this->CompareASomehowToB($a, $b);
   }
}
```

So none of the calls I found in the [docu](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.callable.php) or in any example work. When I skip `uksort` and use `call_user_func` the result is exactly the same.

So, what might be wrong here?

Comment: ... `myClass` not `someClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `someClass::sorterFunc` which is not defined as it is actually `myClass::sorterFunc` because you are extending `someClass` with `myClass`.

```
uksort($theArray, "myClass::sorterFunc");
```